# Print all objects and attributes of another class from database, ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I print all attributes of all objects of one class's associated class?  Which file should this be in (model, view, controller?).  What functions should I be implementing?

I have 2 classes created in my Ruby on Rails project.  One is called "Candy" with attribute "name" of type string.  The other class is called "Shop".  These classes are associated with a database. Candy belongs to Shop and Shop has many candies.  I am trying to output this in my Shop's view.

I have tried different variations of code similar to these:

```
    <ul>
    <%= Shop.Candies.name.all %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
```

and this:

```
    <% Shop.Candies.name do |Candies| %>
    <ul>
    <% puts Shop.Candies.name %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a variable called `@shop` which you got from doing something like:

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Then, in your view, you might do something like:

```
<ul>
  <% @shop.candies.each do |candy| %>
    <li>
      <%= candy.name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This:

```
Shop.Candies.name.all
```

is a hot mess because (minimally):

- The method for getting the candies associated with a shop is `candies`, not `Candies` (capitalization matters).
- `candies` is a method on an instance of `Shop` (e.g., `@shop`, in my example), not a method on the `Shop` class. So, `Shop.Candies` doesn't make sense (nor does `Shop.candies`). But, `@shop.candies` makes perfect sense.
- `name` is a method on an instance of `Candy`. Since `Candies` isn't meaningful, then `Candies.name` also isn't meaningful. But, `candy.name` makes sense.
- I have no idea what that `all` is doing hanging off the end of all that.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the difference with capitalization in ROR. I tried different variations of what you recommended, and I am currently getting a different error now, "undefined method `candies' for nil:NilClass".  Should it be ".each" as opposed to " each"?
<ul>
  <% @shop.candies.each do |candy| %>
    <li>
      <%= candy.name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

Comment: Yes, it should. Sorry about that. Edited. Also, that `undefined method` error indicates that your `@shop` variable is `nil`. So, you're not setting it correctly.

Comment: No worries! Thank you, you have clarified a lot for me!

Comment: Thank you, I will look up how I can set it correctly